# IF ELSE Condition inside FORALL Oracle

Tags: if-statement, plsql, bulkinsert, bulk-load, forall

Can you guys share with how to do **IF ELSE** Inside a **FORALL**?

This is my current code that working fine.

FOR DECLARATION;

```
TYPE t_column1 IS TABLE OF USERS.column1%TYPE;
TYPE t_column2 IS TABLE OF USERS.column1%TYPE;

arr_column1     t_column1;
arr_column2     t_column2;

TYPE t_columnA IS TABLE OF ADDRESS.columnA%TYPE;
TYPE t_columnB IS TABLE OF ADDRESS.columnA%TYPE;

arr_columnA t_columnA := t_columnA();
arr_columnB t_columnB := t_columnB();

CURSOR cur IS
    SELECT column1,column2
    FROM USERS;

i       INTEGER;
l_done  BOOLEAN;
indx    INTEGER;
```

MAIN CODE:

```
OPEN cur;
LOOP
    FETCH cur BULK COLLECT INTO
    arr_column1, arr_column2
    LIMIT 10000;

    l_done := curRESALEMASTER%NOTFOUND;

    FOR indx IN 1 .. arr_column1.COUNT
    LOOP
        arr_columnA.extend;
        arr_columnB.extend;

        arr_columnA(indx) := arr_column1(indx);
        arr_columnB(indx) := 'XYZ';

    END LOOP;

    FORALL i IN 1 .. arr_column1.COUNT
        INSERT INTO ADDRESS partition VALUES (
            arr_columnA(i),
            arr_columnB(i),
            arr_column2(i);

    EXIT WHEN (l_done);

END LOOP;
COMMIT;
CLOSE cur;
```

So my issue is how to put condition for **FORALL**?

It will be something like:

```
    FORALL i IN 1 .. arr_column1.COUNT
    IF arr_columnA(indx) <> NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO ADDRESS partition VALUES (
            arr_columnA(i),
            arr_columnB(i),
            arr_column2(i);
    END IF;
```

But I cannot put condition inside FORALL

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: PL/SQL - ORACLE. Sorry forgot to mention in title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can't compare a NULL with a variable.
You have to use

```
   IS [NOT] NULL
```

To answer your question, I would try this:

```
 FORALL i IN arr_column1.FIRST .. arr_column1.LAST
        INSERT INTO ADDRESS partition
        SELECT
            arr_columnA(i),
            arr_columnB(i),
            arr_column2(i)
        FROM DUAL
        WHERE arr_columnA(indx) IS NOT NULL
  ;
```